# Connecting to a tmux session in a running Google Cloud Dataflow worker

Tags: tmux, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm doing something that I thought was moderately clever, and it has predictably come back to bite me.

I have a compiled binary my workers download and shell out to.
This binary takes a long time to start (60s), and then it listens on stdin and emits on stdout.
To avoid paying the startup cost more than once per worker, I start the binary in a tmux session in `startBundle`. In `processElement`, I use a `tmux send-keys` command to pipe the work item to the running tmux session and then read out the results.

Specifically, the tmux start command is:

```
tmux new-session -d -s word2vecdistance "./distance GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin > /tmp/word2vec_distance_log.txt"
```

A query might look like this:

```
tmux send-keys -t word2vecdistance love C-m
```

This is definitely convoluted, but it works locally for me, both in my unit tests and if I use the `DirectPipelineRunner`.
However, if I run in the cloud, the query command would result in this tmux error:

```
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
```

My guess is tmux wants some permissions / ports that aren't available in the Docker workers Dataflow uses, but that's as far as I've gotten.

You wisdom would be appreciated.

CLARIFICATION 0: This all happens inside a single (Dataflow) Docker container, i.e. I'm trying to connect to a tmux session that's in the same container.

CLARIFICATION 1: I don't think I can control how Docker containers are invoked; this is something Google Cloud Dataflow manages.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

tmux uses unix sockets to communicate between processes. Usually in /tmp/tmux.something. (Depending on your OS + config). One idea would be to share /tmp with all your docker containers (i.e. add `-v /tmp:/tmp` to the docker command.)

But keep in mind that tmux was not designed as a multi-user system, so you may encounter race conditions. If your scripts ask for two words at the same time, their output may be mixed together.

It would be better to write your own service that wraps your word2vecdistance program. (i.e. as a Unix socket or TCP server). It would be a little complex, but allow you to ensure there are no races when multiple clients ask questions at once.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But, I think I didn't explain the situation properly, so I added clarifications to the original question.